# Modify WP_Query using pre_get_posts but only for frontend query?

Tags: wp-query

I am modifying a query using the pre_get_posts filter, but it is affecting the backend page listing when I only want it to affect the frontend query.

I can check using is_admin() but that seems a bit 'hacky'.

Comment: `is_admin()` is completely legit and absolutely necessary when dealing with `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: I think `is_admin()` has a poor reputation because people misuse it thinking that it means 'is user an administrator', but it's perfectly legitimate for this use, and is in fact suggested in [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#A_Warning_About_Admin_Usage).

Comment: Hey Paul could you please add your current code to your question for clarification?

Answer (score 1):

Using `is_admin()` is not hacky, as pointed out in the comments.

You should definitely check for `is_admin()` when modifying frontend queries. If you're modifying the main query, also use the `is_main_query()` function / method.

Comment: Is `is_main_query()` for the frontend or backend?

Comment: It's for the front end as it checks the `$wp_the_query` global which I don't think is ever defined in the admin :-)